# Can the NODAL DK Method Be used for discretizing an analog circuit with OTAs?

Tags: analog-to-digital, analog

I'm exploring the discretization of analog circuits and have come across the NODAL DK method as a potential technique. I'm curious if this method is suitable for circuits that incorporate Operational Transconductance Amplifiers (OTAs). Are there special considerations one should take into account when applying the NODAL DK method to such circuits?